# Generate a Unique String in Python/Django

Tags: python, django

What I want is to generate a string(key) of size 5 for my users on my website. More like a BBM PIN.

The key will contain numbers and uppercase English letters:

- **AU1B7**
- **Y56AX**
- **M0K7A**

How can I also be at rest about the uniqueness of the strings even if I generate them in millions?

In the most pythonic way possible, how can I do this?

Comment: `base64.b32encode('12345') == 'GEZDGNBV'`

Comment: se also https://github.com/jbittel/base32-crockford

Comment: You can generate them with `django.utils.crypto.get_random_string(5, string.ascii_uppercase+string.digits)`. You might want to restrict the set of characters so that you don't generate potentially confusing strings such as `l1I1l` which might be indecipherable in certain fonts. Uniqueness is going to require that you persist the set of allocated strings.

Comment: You can't have both "random" *and* "unique". Replace the "random" with "random-looking".

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams: Why didn't you register that observation instead of your conclusion? It's misleading.

Comment: Because I am the crusher of dreams, the bringer of woe and despair. WOE AND DESPAIR.

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams: I was at your site, your book. This isn't WOE AND DESPAIR. Those who bring woe and despair do it the right way. They are not angry. You just have blown up digits. Not all have their lives tied to coding, some do it for the fun of it.

Answer (score 70, accepted):

My favourite is

```
import uuid 
uuid.uuid4().hex[:6].upper()
```

If you using django you can set the unique constrain on this field in order to make sure it is unique. https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.Field.unique

Comment: +1 for the length of the code. But I was curious about how you are sure that you are generating unique values ? Doesn't it generate repeated values ?

Comment: Sure there could be collisions! http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universally_unique_identifier#Random_UUID_probability_of_duplicates The longer uuid the chances of collision are slimmer. Basically  there need to be some further logic to it as all depens HOW you are going about generating and storing them.

Comment: This isn't going to generate AU1B7, Y56AX, nor M0K7A as alpha characters are limited to A..F. It's not going to generate guaranteed unique values either. You could add the code to show how to handle collisions.

Comment: You could handle collisions like [in this SO question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3928016/)

Comment: This generates a hex string. You literally can't generate millions (plural) with it. But you can generate a million.

Answer (score 21):

From 3.6 You can use secrets module to generate nice random strings.
https://docs.python.org/3/library/secrets.html#module-secrets

```
import secrets
print(secrets.token_hex(5))
```

Comment: This generates a hex string. You literally can't generate millions (plural) with it. But you can generate a million.

Answer (score 20):

A more secure and shorter way of doing is using Django's crypto module.

```py
from django.utils.crypto import get_random_string
code = get_random_string(5)
```

`get_random_string()` function returns a securely generated random string, uses
`secrets` module under the hood.

You can also pass `allowed_chars`:

```py
from django.utils.crypto import get_random_string
import string

code = get_random_string(5, allowed_chars=string.ascii_uppercase + string.digits)
```

Answer (score 4):

Am not sure about any short cryptic ways, but it can be implemented using a simple straight forward function assuming that you save all the generated strings in a set:

```
import random

def generate(unique):
    chars = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ1234567890"
    while True:
        value = "".join(random.choice(chars) for _ in range(5))
        if value not in unique:
            unique.add(value)
            break

unique = set()
for _ in range(10):
    generate(unique)
```

Comment: Just to highlight that it's stated on python's `secret` [package page](https://docs.python.org/3/library/secrets.html#module-secrets): "In particularly, secrets should be used in preference to the default pseudo-random number generator in the random module, which is designed for modelling and simulation, not security or cryptography."

Comment: Upvote for using python sets for a collection of unique elements.

Answer (score 4):

If you can afford to lose '8' and '9' in the generated numbers there is a very pythonic solution to getting a random number.

```py
import os
import base64

base64.b32encode(os.urandom(3))[:5].decode('utf-8')
```

Since you are going for uniqueness then you have a problem since `36 * 36 * 36 * 36 * 36 = 60'466'176` which will definitely result in collisions if you have millions. Since sets are faster than dicts we do...

```
some_set = set()

def generate():
    return base64.b32encode(os.urandom(3))[:5].decode('utf-8')

def generate_unique():
    string = generate()
    while string in some_set:
        string = generate()
    some_set.add(string)
    return string
```

However since uniqueness is usually more important I'd recommend generating a unique code for each of the numbers from `0 to 36^5 - 1` like this. We can use a large prime and modulo to make a psuedo-random number like this.

```
import base64
import math

num = 1
prime_number = 60466181
characters = 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ123456789'

def num_to_code(n: int):
    string = ''
    hashed = hash_number(n)
    for x in range(5):
        charnumber = hashed % 36
        hashed = math.floor(hashed / 36)
        string += characters[charnumber]
    return string

def hash_number(n: int, rounds = 20):
    if rounds <= 0:
        return n
    hashed = (n * prime_number) % (36 ** 5)
    return hash_number(hashed, rounds - 1)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    code = num_to_code(1)
    print(code)
```

Here are the results from generating 0-5, they'll always generate the same sequence.

```
0 AAAAA (easily fixable ofc)
1 ZGQR9
2 ON797
3 DUMQ6
4 31384
5 R8IP3
```

Answer (score 3):

If you have a way of associating each user to a unique ID (for example `Primary Key` in Django or Flask). You can do something like this:

**Note:** This does not generate a fixed length.

We will pad the `user_id` to the right to make the generated length a bit static

```
import os
import base64

user_id = 1

#pad the string
number_generate = str(user_id).rjust(5,"0")

base64.b32encode(bytes(number_generate, 'utf-8')).decode('utf-8').replace('=','')
```

Comment: This approach is the only way to make it "Unique" and should be the accepted answer imo.

Answer (score 1):

```
size = 5
''.join(random.choice(string.letters[26:] + string.digits) for in range(size))
```

this will generate some short code, but they can be duplicated. so check if they are unique in your database before saving.

```
def generate(size=5):
    code = ''.join(random.choice(string.letters[26:] + string.digits) for in range(size))
    if check_if_duplicate(code):
        return generate(size=5)
    return code
```

or using django unique constrain, and handle exceptions.

Comment: Could you clarify what is `string.letters` and `string.digits`?

Comment: He means `string.ascii_letters`

Answer (score 1):

There is a function in django that does what you're looking for (credits to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25949808/1396264)):

> Django provides the function `get_random_string()` which will satisfy
>   the alphanumeric string generation requirement. You don't need any
>   extra package because it's in the `django.utils.crypto` module.
>
> ```
> >>> from django.utils.crypto import get_random_string
> >>> unique_id = get_random_string(length=32)
> >>> unique_id
> u'rRXVe68NO7m3mHoBS488KdHaqQPD6Ofv'
> ```
>
> You can also vary the set of characters with `allowed_chars`:
>
> ```
> >>> short_genome = get_random_string(length=32, allowed_chars='ACTG')
> >>> short_genome
> u'CCCAAAAGTACGTCCGGCATTTGTCCACCCCT'
> ```

Answer (score 1):

I have a unique field, named '**systemCode**' within a lot of my models. And I am generating this manually, but also sometimes it can take value from user input, so I have to check this value before saving and if it matches , regenerating this value as a unique value.

And this is how I generate unique strings at this scenario :

---

> This is my standard class Model :

```
class ClassOne(models.Model):
   name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
   systemCode = models.CharField(max_length=25, blank=True, null=True, unique=True)
   ....
```

> I am using *save()* method to generate and check this **systemCode** is unique :

```
    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        systemCode = self.systemCode
        if not systemCode:
            systemCode = uuid.uuid4().hex[:6].upper()
        while ClassOne.objects.filter(systemCode=systemCode).exclude(pk=self.pk).exists():
            systemCode = uuid.uuid4().hex[:6].upper()
        self.systemCode = systemCode
        super(ClassOne, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

But I have same **systemCode** field in all my Models. So I am using a function to generate value.

> So, this is how to generate unique value for all models using ***saveSystemCode()*** function :

```
import uuid 

def saveSystemCode(inClass, inCode, inPK, prefix):
    systemCode = inCode
    if not systemCode:
        systemCode = uuid.uuid4().hex[:6].upper()

    while inClass.objects.filter(systemCode=systemCode).exclude(pk=inPK).exists():
        systemCode = uuid.uuid4().hex[:6].upper()

    return systemCode

class ClassOne(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    systemCode = models.CharField(max_length=25, blank=True, null=True, unique=True)
    ....

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.systemCode = saveSystemCode(ClassOne, self.systemCode, self.pk, 'one_')
        super(ClassOne, self).save(*args, **kwargs)


class ClassTwo(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    systemCode = models.CharField(max_length=25, blank=True, null=True, unique=True)
    ....

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.systemCode = saveSystemCode(ClassTwo, self.systemCode, self.pk, 'two_')
        super(ClassTwo, self).save(*args, **kwargs)

class ClassThree(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    systemCode = models.CharField(max_length=25, blank=True, null=True, unique=True)
    ....

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.systemCode = saveSystemCode(ClassThree, self.systemCode, self.pk, 'three_')
        super(ClassThree, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

---

*while* loop in the '**saveSystemCode**' function is preventing to save same value again.

Answer (score 1):

To generate unique one you can use below command:

```
import uuid 
str(uuid.uuid1())[:5]
```

Answer (score 1):

Here a solution to gen codes of lenght 5 or any on a file:

```
import shortuuid as su
n = int(input("# codes to gen: "))
l = int(input("code lenght: "))
shou = su.ShortUUID(alphabet="QWERTYUIOPASDFGHJKLZXCVBNM0123456789")
codes = set()
LEN_CNT = 0

with open('file.txt', 'w') as file:
    while len(codes) < n:
        cd = shou.random(length=l)
        codes.add(cd)
        if len(codes) > LEN_CNT:
            LEN_CNT = len(codes)
            file.write(f"{cd}\n")
```

(shortuuid sometimes gen duplicated codes, so I use a set to deal with that)

Answer (score 0):

As the time of writing this answer, there is an actively maintained package that generates short UUIDs:

https://github.com/skorokithakis/shortuuid

For Django support, have a look here:

https://github.com/skorokithakis/shortuuid#django-field